# Linking MS Access table to PG Admin schema

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, pgadmin

I would like to link a MS Access table to a table in PG admin if it is possible for use in a Postgres query. I have searched for an answer but all I can find is answers for listing postgres tables in Access which is almost the opposite of what I want to do.

I want to be able to access the data entered in an access form without having to continually import the data into a table in PG Admin.

I'm not even sure that is possible but any method that is easier than importing the table into PG Admin every day would be useful.

Thanks
Gary

Answer (score 0):

Try the PostgreSQL OGR Foreign Data Wrapper. Its built for spatial data, but it works perfectly well with non-spatial tables. If you have the PostGIS extension installed you will already have it.

https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-ogr-fdw

There are several examples on that page, but the command

```
ogr_fdw_info -s <pathToAccessFile> -l <tablename>
```

will return create server and a create foreign table statements which you can edit as required then run in pgAdmin.